# Автоматическая проверка на уязвимости

Tags: веб-программирование, безопасность, xss

Существует ли opensource GPL* решение, для автоматизации поиска web-уязвимостей? Например какой-нибудь XSS Scanner, либо что-то подобное но в масштабах сканирования кучи хостов?

Вы не подумайте, я не кульцхацкер, просто у меня есть некоторое кол-во сайтов которые то добавляются, то удаляются, в общем, что-то типа хостинга и иногда от гугла приходят письма "Hacked content detected on ..." за что я гуглу благодарен, но всё же хотел бы сам это как-то обнаруживать автоматически. Я уверен, есть какие-нибудь конвейерные решения по сканированию своих хостов на web-уязвимости.

Comment: Например есть sqlmap

Comment: Нашёл [wapiti](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Automated_Audit_using_WAPITI) но проект обновлялся 2013 года :( Установил, затестил, штука вроде не плохая, но очень старая версия... в общем, пока ищу ещё варианты.

Comment: ... а ещё он однопоточный :(

Comment: А кто вам мешает запустить несколько процессов одновременно?

Comment: Предпочитаю многопоточность/мультипроцессорность/асинхронность реализованную на стороне приложения.